# Settings serializer adds to arrays with defaults instead of replacing them

Tags: c#, c#-6.0

I have an issue where loading `Settings.Default` will add deserialized items to the list instead of replacing the list. Take the following for example:

```
class UserSettings
{
    public List<string> foos = new() { "foo", "bar" };
}
```

Settings.Settings

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<SettingsFile xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/2004/01/settings" CurrentProfile="(Default)" GeneratedClassNamespace="PhotoComparer.Properties" GeneratedClassName="Settings">
  <Profiles />
  <Settings>
    <Setting Name="UserSettings" Type="ProjectName.UserSettings" Scope="User">
      <Value Profile="(Default)" />
    </Setting>
  </Settings>
</SettingsFile>
```

App.Config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
</configuration>
```

If I add a new `UserSettings` and do a `Settings.Default.Save()` and close the application then start it back up again to load the default settings again `Settings.Default.UserSettings` is now equal to `List<string>(4) {"foo", "bar", "foo", "bar"}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found adding an array property worked the best while not losing the performance of small lists.

```
class UserSettings
{
    [XmlIgnore]
    public List<string> foos = new() { "foo", "bar" };
    [XmlArray("foos")]
    public string[] sfoos { get => foos.ToArray(); set => foos = new(value); }
}
```

After saving and re-opening twice results in `List<string>(2) {"foo", "bar"}`.

Answer (score 0):

That's how `List<T>` works. Try `HashSet<T>`.